# Remove full name from Google search?

Tags: discussion, google, display-names

I have a Stack Overflow account with a chosen nickname for myself. When my account shows in a Google search, my name and surname are displayed. When I open the link, everything is alright and my nickname is displayed instead of my name and surname.

How do I change to have my nickname everywhere, instead of my full name?

Comment: Take a look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89975/when-i-google-for-my-real-name-my-stack-overflow-profile-shows-up-as-a-popular

Comment: Did you change your user name very recently?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/